# UIActionSheet messes up shaking detection (motionBegan: delegate) on iPad

Tags: ipad, uiactionsheet, shake

In my App, I use a UIActionSheet (nothing fancy) and present it (standard) using showFromBarButtonItem: and dismissing it using it's delegate clickedButtonAtIndex:. All simple and nice. Also I use the motionBegan: to detect a shake to do various stuff.

My App runs fine on an iPhone.

But, on the iPad as soon as the actionSheet is presented (once) the motionBegan: stops working! Any shake of the device (simulator) does not register! Before the actionSheet presentation, all shakes where register fine. As soon as it is presented, it stops.

I added a [actionSheetNav resignFirstResponder]; in the actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex: delegate (if that was a problem) but with no effect.

Any ideas?
(I could post the code, but nothing works even if the 1st command of (each related) method is a NSLog & a return immediately after)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!

I just had to add a

```
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
```

after the

```
    [actionSheetNav resignFirstResponder];
```

line in the actionSheet delegate

```
-(IBAction)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)sender clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)myButton
```